# How to match the versions or Susbstrate upstream in my project's dependancies?

Tags: rust, versioning

I'm new to substrate and follow this tutorial: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt1/.
I'm facing problem in this line : **we'll need to import serde. Add this to your pallet's Cargo.toml file, using the matching version as Substrate upstream.**
how to import serde and match it to the substrate upstream ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s more of a case specific support question.

Comment: I edited the title and tags to be more descriptive and general

Answer (score 5):

Add the following (the lines with the `<--- add this` comment to the `[dependencies]` and `[features]` section of the `cargo.toml` file:

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.119" }  //<----- add this


[features]
default = ['std']
std = [
    'serde/std',  //<----- add this
]
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it this out.

Answer (score 0):

`cargo tree | grep serde` can be used to get the package specific versions needed for `serde`. Here you can see what substrate libs need, and match what substrate uses.

Also manually matching what existing in the [`Cargo.toml` of  your upstream crates](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/cli/Cargo.toml#L27-L28) can work too.